# Getting confused while using KeyListener's 3 methods in Swing?

Tags: java, awt, keylistener, japplet, keystroke

I'm trying to build a `textfield` which can accept only numbers. I tried many times but I'm getting the behavior of 3 methods.
The three methods call at same time, but all methods return different values for `getKeyCode()` method. Why do these methods return different values? And another thing, when I tried for adding `keyListener` to JApplet, it doesn't accept key values? Why?

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleKey1 extends JApplet implements KeyListener
{
     String msg="";


     JTextField jTextField;
     int x = 10, y = 20; 

     public void init()
     {
         addKeyListener(this);

         requestFocus();
     }

     @Override
     public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        showStatus("Key Pressed");
     }

     @Override
     public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        showStatus("Key Released");
     }

     @Override
     public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
         msg+=arg0.getKeyChar();
         repaint();
     }

     public void paint(Graphics g)
     {
         g.drawString(msg, x, y);
     }

}
```

Comment: *"And another thing.."* You seem to be confusing this Q&A site for a help desk. Please limit it to one question per Q&A thread (ask as many new threads as needed).

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: @Andrew I didn't understand what u r saying? (ask as many new threads as needed) what does it mean? can u please tell me? n tell me how do I ask questions? I'm not getting the behaviour of these 3 methods? These 3 methods call at same time for some keys and some times only 2 methods call? Can u explain me the behaviour of these methods. And by the way this code is not specified by my teacher. This is not assignment, I'm keen learner

Comment: The title of this question is *"Getting confused while using KeyListener's 3 methods in Swing?"* ..imagine if someone can answer that, but not *"..when I tried for adding keyListener to JApplet, it doesn't accept key values? Why?"*.  Should they try to answer one of the two questions, or just ignore this one completely and go on to the next where they can answer all 'one' of the questions asked? Many people would not bother thinking about it, and simply move to the next question. Further, this is intended to be a searchable resource for others later to find answers. If I'm looking for the ..

Comment: .. question ""..when I tried for adding keyListener to JApplet, it doesn't accept key values? Why?"" why would I click on a search result for a question titled *"Getting confused while using KeyListener's 3 methods in Swing?"* they are not the same. This (the question and any answers) is what I'm calling a 'question thread'. You can ask as many as you have questions for, so put each on a separate thread and give each a meaningful title.

Comment: *"This is not assignment, I'm keen learner.."* You are wasting time trying to learn applets. They are effectively 'dead'. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: @Andrew then can you tell me where should I focus? What's the new trend in Java? I saw reference books that contains these points? I wanted to develop java application? How can I learn new java concepts and from which point will I start? Is there any new trends other than Swing and Awt in java?

Comment: @Andrew if there is any gramatical mistake in above message please ignore it and try to understand what I wanted to tell u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JFormattedTextField` instead and provide format which accepts only numbers.
No need to code so much for this reason.

Documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html

Comment: There is a code behind JFormattedTextField. I'm trying to build that code. Can u explain me behaviour of all these 3 methods? Sometimes only 2 methods call? Sometimes 3 methods call? How?

Comment: When hold down a key, `keyPressed` event will be fired, if you keep on holding the key, `keyPressed` method will be called for multiple times. When you release the key, `keyReleased` method will be called. combination of `keyPressed` and `keyReleased` is nothing but `keyTyped`. Hope this clears the confusion.